# How to access file tempory in action which is browse by file_field in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to get attached excel files and its path in rails

My view is

```
<%= form_for @hotel, :url => { :action => "create_by_excel_sheet" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :excel_sheet %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

and when submit the form the attached excel file I want to receive in create_by_excel_sheet action

I tried

`params["hotel"]["excel_sheet"].tempfile.path` then it return `"/tmp/RackMultipart20130921-3387-1ffc97o"` not a file path.

```
Ex: /file_path/file_name.file_extension
```

Answer (score 0):

> then it return "/tmp/RackMultipart20130921-3387-1ffc97o" not a file path.

That *is* the file path. Temp files reside in `/tmp` and have large pseduo-random names. They do not need file extensions. It's up to you to read the file or copy it to a more permanent location.

Comment: When I reading this file with `roo` gem like `Roo::Spreadsheet.open("/tmp/RackMultipart20130921-3387-1ffc97o")` getting error `LoadError Exception: Using Roo::Google requires the google_drive gem` and I have also used this gem

Answer (score 0):

Install the google drive gem, roo has dependency for certain gems which are included in google-drive:

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby

After this i did,

```
p Roo::Spreadsheet.open(params['file_to_upload'].path, extension: :xlsx)

---> {[1, 1]=>"qwrwe", [1, 2]=>"rqwerwqe", [1, 3]=>"we", [1, 4]=>"wer", [1, 5]=>"erqwe", [1, 6]=>"rwqerwer"
```